# typing exponents on trig functions from sage latex command

Tags: latex, sage

the command `print(latex(sin(x)*sin(x)))` returns something like this $$\sin(x)^2$$. However, I would like it to return something like this instead  $$\sin^2(x)$$ I am new to sage and I am guessing there is a correct way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that explains that it is not possible at the moment:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/-FxOZmHhcgo